# Listview.builder no me elimina la posición deseada, elimina la ultima y estoy seguro que le paso la posición correcta

Tags: flutter, dart

¡Hola! Tengo un listview.builder que carga una lista de productos desde provider, el builder funciona a la perfección si uso un widget Text como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de cambiar el Text por un TextFormField no permite eliminar la posición que deseo como se ve en la imagen, siempre me elimina el ultimo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya verifique y si estoy pasando la posición correcta para eliminar, es mas elimina en provider de manera correcta el problema es con el TEXTFORMFIELD. aqui agrego el widget.

```
class _Features extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<_Features> createState() => _FeaturesState();
}

class _FeaturesState extends State<_Features> {
  String descriptionFeature = '';

  final fieldText = TextEditingController();

  void clearText() {
    fieldText.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
            controller: fieldText,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: 2,
            maxLength: 254,
            onChanged: (value) => descriptionFeature = value,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Agregre una nueva carácteristica del producto",
                labelText: 'Carácteristica',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))),
                focusColor: Colors.white)),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Center(
            child: CustomOutlinedButton(
                isFilled: true,
                color: Colors.blue,
                text: 'Agregar Carácteristica',
                onPressed: () => product.features.length <= 4
                    ? descriptionFeature.isEmpty
                        ? false
                        : {
                            product.addFeatureDescription(descriptionFeature),
                            product.addFeatureObservation(null),
                            clearText(),
                            setState(() {
                              descriptionFeature = '';
                            })
                          }
                    : false)),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Text(
          'Mis carácteristicas agregados',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 14),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 380,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: product.features.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 250,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          initialValue: product.features[index],
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              product.deleteFeature(index);
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.close))
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
},
```

No se si depronto alguien me pueda dar un poco de luz sobre el tema, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A lo que veo tienes una lista de objetos, al momento de ejecutar el onchange puedes pasarle el value que en teoría es el texto de ese objeto dejando las otras propiedades.

yo recomiendo uses el siguiente código

```
 int index = listaobjetos.indexWhere((element) => element.texto== value);
 listaobjetos.removeAt(index);
```

vas a buscar el índice del objeto que vas a eliminar del arreglo accediendo a su propiedad y comparando con el valor seleccionado, después con el remove te solicita un índice el cual ya tienes y eliminara el objeto en la posición correcta de tu arreglo, espero te sirva.